# connect oracle db with odbc via ipaddress , datas from another system

Tags: php, oracle, odbc, ip-address

connect oracle db with odbc via ipaddress 
I need to connect oracle db via network ip address from my one of php page.

```
$conn=odbc_connect('(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 128.212.160.2:prod)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))','username','*******');
```

this is what am getting when executed

Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length, SQL state S1090 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracleconnect\odbccnt.php on line 34

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to Oracle using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83040/connecting-to-oracle-using-php)

Comment: new/existing code? why not switch to OCI8 latest version?

Comment: DoSparkot itz new code ,do u think OCI8 is better? i dont know , here am new bee to orale

Comment: what i want is to connect my system with another oracle db to handle the data via ip address , can anyone suggest best solution for this