# joomla 2.5 - oracle database in different server connectivity

Tags: oracle, joomla, database-connection, joomla2.5

Is it possible to connect to oracle database in a remote server in joomla 2.5 ? I need to set up a 2-way connectivity..1 with the db in my own server which is mysql(configured in configuration.php file) and also a remote oracle db.. Can anyone please help?

Connection string :

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID = db)))
```

username : uname, password : pwd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has also been asked here:
[Connecting to Oracle using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83040/connecting-to-oracle-using-php)

Did you see this?

Joomla itself is not compatible with Oracle even up to version 3.0.

Obviously what you are asking about is more of a bridge and should be very possible.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the link you had posted but that is for plain php. I wanted to know whether there is any method by which I can connect joomla to oracle database. Thanks for the reply. Guess I will code it in plain php and get the data in joomla. Thanks again.

Comment: I and others would be interested to hear how you get on with that.